# Need to store latest 5 months of data in a table on delete and insert mode

Tags: mysql, sql, netezza

I have tried a scenario which needs to store last 5 months of data in netezza. below is the code which I've tried. But after that I got a wired thought and struck there to solve that.

```
create table test(yermon int,number int);

insert into test values(201607,1);
insert into test values(201606,2);
insert into test values(201605,3);
insert into test values(201604,4);
insert into test values(201603,5);
```

And then if I insert a new record with new yearmonth my below logic is working.

```
delete from test where  yermon in (select min(yermon) from test where no=5);
update test set no = no + 1;
insert into test values(201608,1);
```

But if I run the same again twice. 201607 will go and store twice and 201603 ll delete.

I need a delete and update statement to include this situation as well. Can some one please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need the `number` at all. You can generate it on-the-fly in a select

Comment: i just added number for my reference easily. if we have solution with out that we can remove that as well.

Comment: create primary key on yermon field

Comment: Call me old-fashioned, but I would rather save a `date` I could do date math with that something like this. Not only is it 3 bytes vs 6, but functions to boot.

Comment: for my bad luck Netezza doesn't have primary key concept.

Comment: @Dileep no! You can! read the docs: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_create_table.html

Comment: Very Good Info. But we cannot use any of the constraints. because based on yermon column i will have more than 1k data and without a no how can we prevent table should has last 5 months of data.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try this?

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  year_month int(6),
  number int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY year_month
);
```

I've found [`MERGE INTO` statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_merge.html), maybe I'm wrong, but test it:

```
MERGE INTO test AS dst USING test AS src ON (src.year_month=201608)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dst.number = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES(201608, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, it's like INSERT if not exist, or UPDATE if exist. PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY constraint helps.

Comment: REPLACE is there in Netezza? i'm not getting any examples.

Comment: @Dileep wait a little, looking for example

Comment: @Dileep try my answer.

Comment: Netezza does not enforce UNIQUE constraints at all.